# DateTime Input mask does not work with MVC model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, input-mask

I am working on a project that has users input dates and times.  In order to force them to put the dates in correctly I am using an input mask.  The input mask is showing up.  However, in the edit page it will not show the value of that field (if one is saved already) but the input mask does show up.

Here is the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.expiration_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "datetime-local" } })
```

If I remove the input mask then the saved value for that field will show but of course not the input mask.  How do I get both to work together?

Without:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.expiration_date)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but you could always use a date time picker which would solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks @James but there are two problems with the datetime picker. First, from a user perspective, most users (at least at my job) type out their input more often than use the mouse.  Second, I tried a datetime picker as well and could not get it to work.  I may test around more with it though.

Comment: Since datetime-local is not supported in every browser ( [IE and FF don't](http://caniuse.com/#search=datetime-local) ) try to use this plugin: https://github.com/jonstipe/datetime-local-polyfill and check if it works as expected.. please check also that your `model.expiration_date` is a DateTimeProperty

Comment: @MartinoBordin thank you.  I didn't even realize that it doesn't work in IE or FF because I did not start testing on other browsers yet.  However, do you know know if that should work with my model (I mean solve the problem I have hear as well)?

Comment: @djblois understandable, when I've previously used them I've always had difficulties, but that's normally either due to conflicts with other plugins or parsing dates in the wrong format. I find it's normally easier to parse everything as strings and then convert them to a DateTime object as and when you need them.